# What is the meaning of this legal statement?

Tags: meaning

Evidence act:

> In civil cases character to prove conduct imputed, irrelevant. —In
> civil cases, the fact that the character of any person concerned is
> such as to render probable or improbable any conduct imputed to him,
> is irrelevant, except in so far as such character appears from facts
> otherwise relevant.

Can someone tell me the meaning of the statement
"*except in so far as such character appears from facts otherwise relevant*" ?

Can't this entire paragraph be shorten to

> In civil cases the character of any person concerned is irrelevant.

without any ambiguity?

Comment: It means that you can judge someone's character only by the facts, not by their reputation. IOW if someone is "known" to be a liar, it does not mean they probably lied in this case.

Comment: '. but if they gave the police a statement including a demonstrably deliberate untruth, the truth value of the rest of their statement should be viewed with this duplicity in mind.' is one possible interpretation.

Comment: Your source is an Indian legal text more that 150 years old! I hope you're not expecting to learn anything useful about current mainstream English from it! *Why* are you reading it?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because law.stackexchange.com is a better forum. The interpretation of legal language is often not straightforward, and often not consistent with non-legal contexts.

Comment: Of course it can't be shortened and preserve the meaning of the paragraph. The paragraph is that long because the author wanted to mean something more than just the single sentence. Could you 'get away with' just the one sentence (hoping that the reader can make the same inferences that the full paragraph does for them)? Maybe, but the single sentence does not mean the same thing as the paragraph.

Comment: There is nothing in the quoted provision that requires an explanation so far as English language is concerned; its grammatical structure and the meanings of the words used are fairly clear. If what you are interested in is what role the different parts of the quoted provision play in its application, that calls for studying the caselaw of the jusridiction in question, which is outside the scope of this site.

Comment: What language does that come from, please? What could 'In civil cases character to prove conduct imputed, irrelevant' really mean, and how could that doubt not call the whole passage into question?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin, the first part of the quotation is a heading; it is not meant to be a grammatically complete sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Opinions on legal issues are notorious for legalese and apparent obfuscation and abstruseness. I imagine that even experts in the law may at times find some statements, such as the one in your question, hard to interpret.

What for me makes the "in so far" statement somewhat understandable is its inclusion of the word ***relevant***. Since the entire quotation begins with the key word ***irrelevant***, a reader could logically infer there is a rule of thumb regarding the potential relationship between a person's known character and their actual behavior.

Think of character as a person's *ethos* or reputation. A person acquires a bad reputation, in part, from past behavior that has been judged by others to be deceitful, evasive, suspicious, illegal, immoral or unethical. However, when a judge is expected to render a verdict in a civil case, the judgment must be based on the preponderance of evidence, and the only relevant evidence must come from provable facts.

If, for example, the judge catches the defendant in a lie in the giving of testimony, that lie could result in a judgment against the defendant, whether their reputation is stellar or their reputation has been sullied by past indiscretions. That lie could be so incriminating, that the burden of proof in the case (viz., a preponderance of evidence) could be met by the defendant having told one lie.

Could the writer of the entire quotation have done a better job of explaining the irrelevance or relevance of character to a defendant's guilt or innocence? Yes. Your paraphrase, "In civil cases the character of any person concerned is irrelevant" is quite accurate and perspicacious. It must, however, be followed by "unless that character is revealed by relevant and provable facts."